# Организация коллективной разработки сайта.

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Всем привет. Хотелось бы узнать уже у людей сталкивающихся с коллективной разработкой сайта.

Я создал сайт, который быстро развивается и нуждается в развитие, а одному тяжело будет справиться. Таким образом, хотелось бы нанять пару людей (программистов), для работы над сайтом.

Для начала (из-за переезда в другой город), хочу нанять на удаленную работу, но как с ними работать опыта нет. Есть опасения по поводу "незнакомых мне людей (фрилансеров)", так как они могут сделать неподобающее для сайта. Например: Получить доступ к базе, украсть код, данные, навредить и т.д. Но для разработки нужно знать как можно больше информации о сайте и видеть уже старый код сайта для работы.

Как быть в таком случае? Как работать с такими людьми над сайтом? Да и в принципе, хотелось бы узнать как ведется работа и в не удаленной работе? Выслушаю любые советы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Обязательно используйте систему контроля версий, мне нравится [Git](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git),  это упростит совместную работу над сайтом. И в случае если фрилансер накосячит, поможет быстренько откатится. Кстати есть замечательный сервис [github](https://github.com/) который предоставляет полностью настроенные Git репозитарии, в том числе и приватные, за небольшую плату.

2) По поводу фрилансеров ваши опасения вполне справедливы. Как минимум составьте официальный договор с фрилансером по которому он будет нести финансовую ответсвенность за сохранность ваших данных.

Comment: WoW! Прекрасно. Раньше пользовался github'ом для того чтобы получать библиотеки, но не думал что у них есть приватные репозитарии. Будем пробовать. Единственно плохо, что мультиязычность отсутствует.

Comment: так есть и бесплатные сервисы с приватными репозиториями

Comment: @Gorets, Например?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/   https://xp-dev.com/

Answer (score 2):

1. **Система контроля версий** (СКВ), как уже написал [Павел Вершинин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2927/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD);
2. Отдельно продакшн и девелоперский **серверы**. Девелоперы код пишут-проверяют у себя на локальных копиях, затем коммитят в СКВ, оттуда деплоймент-скрипты разворачивают обновление на dev сервер, все перепроверяется, если ОК — уполномоченный гуру деплоит апдейты из СКВ на продакшн. Т.е. у малонадёжных девелоперов нет прямого хода на продакшн, только через СКВ.
3. Контракты в «этой стране» мало кого держат за тестикулы, главный стимул — оплата. Тут на помощь приходит система **Escrow** — когда заказчик кладёт деньги надёжному посреднику, и исполнитель их получает только после выполнения работы от этого посредника. При спорах решение принимает этот незаинтересованный посредник. Механизм реализован фрилансовыми сайтами, как российскими, так и зарубежными. В какой-то степени его вроде бы поддерживают и некоторые системы эл. платежей.